# Деловые отношения, деловые игры

Tags: лексика

Что собой представляет "Деловая игра"? Деловая игра - всякая игра, развивающая какие-либо деловые навыки? Что есть деловые навыки в таком случае? Навыки, связанные с профессией, с дея-тью, которую профессия предполагает (н-р: музыкант в различных "деловых" играх обучается исполнению технически трудных мест в пр-ниях) или с отношениями, в которые вступает служащий человек (н-р:навыки заключения сделок музыкантов с продюссерами). "Деловой" близок к понятию "служебный", поэтому вопрос и навязался.

Comment: Владимир, мне думается, что на сайте _русского языка_ не стоит использовать такие сокращения: **с дея-тью, н-р, в пр-ниях**.

Comment: Не стоит использовать такие сокращения нигде: это уродство, слепленное из благородных знаков.

Answer (score 1):

Деловая игра - форма и метод обучения, в которой моделируются предметный и социальный аспекты содержания профессиональной деятельности. Предназначена для отработки профессиональных умений и навыков.

Деловые игры  моделируют управленческие, экономические, психологические, педагогические ситуации и дают возможность их анализировать и вырабатывать оптимальные действия в дальнейшем. Деловая игра - это средство развития профессионального творческого мышления, в ходе ее человек приобретает способность анализировать специфические ситуации и решать новые для себя профессиональные задачи.

Вот, например, один из сайтов предлагает сценарий  деловой игры «Производственное совещание». Проводится в конце курса «Менеджмент», когда студенты уже имеют представление о принципах управления и роли процесса производства. Участники игры: сотрудники предприятия (7 человек). В совещании участвуют директор, заместитель по производству, начальник технического отдела, начальник цеха сборки, начальник токарного цеха, бригадир, секретарь; группа экспертов (10 человек). Паровозоремонтный или машиностроительный завод (организация любого профиля со средней или небольшой численностью персонала). Владельцами предприятия не так давно был поставлен новый директор. Он был представлен коллективу и менеджерам завода. Директору предстоит провести оперативное совещание впервые.

Распределение ролей (7 сотрудников и 10 экспертов), ведущий организует информирование участников игры с характеристиками сотрудников на совещании.

Удаление директора на время в другой кабинет «по производственной» необходимости, ведущий доводит до участников информацию о поведении сотрудников на совещании (из характеристик). Присутствующие на совещании отнеслись к новому начальству со скептицизмом и недоверием.

Совещание. Выступление директора, реакция и вопросы от начальников. Дискуссия и коллективное обсуждение вопросов. Каким будет поведение директора на совещании? Что он может сказать или сделать для налаживания деловых контактов с сотрудниками? Какие управленческие решения он может принять при подведении итогов первого оперативного совещания?

Подведение итогов. Выводы от экспертов, от участников игры. Самооценка. Решили ли поставленные задачи, достигли ли целей? - Читайте подробнее на FB.ru: http://fb.ru/article/159475/primeryi-delovyih-igr-stsenariy-delovoy-igryi

Деловая игра позволяет приобрести социальный опыт (коммуникации, принятия решений и т.п.),вырабатывает уверенность в себе,  знание особенностей и технологии работы, способов ее усовершенствования.    Умение правильно выбирать средства и реальные методики достижения наилучших результатов,креативность, стрессоустойчивость, умение проявлять сдержанность собственной реакции по отношению к ситуации или действиям сотрудников,     эмоциональную уравновешенность, умение профессионально наладить процесс деятельности так, что каждый из сотрудников четко понимает свои задачи и стремится к их эффективному исполнению.